# How is the radial gradient added here?

Tags: css

http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/39055.html

I've seen bunch of websites having those natural gradient on their backgrounds while surfing the internet. The thing I do not understand is... how did they do that? I don't think it's a photoshop-created image file cuz the gradient seems like re-sizing naturally and properly according to the screen size of my web browser... So, I thought it must be CSS... but I cannot find which code is actually doing the job :/

Could someone tell me how it's done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple background image.

**style.css, line 6:**

```css
body {background:#fff url(../images/body-bg.jpg) 50% 50%; ...
```

Comment: I checked that one too... However, the bg img doesn't seem to have the gradient effect... does it?

Comment: I don't know how you checked it, but [this one](http://static.livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_39055/images/body-bg.jpg) seems to have a gradient.

Comment: Ohhhhh............ wow.... I feel so embarrassed :/   I believed it must be a fancy trick using CSS.... thank you.

Comment: // I checked it using the preview mode in Fire Bug :(  I should have 'actually' opened the file... how dumb I am.. Thank you guys

Comment: @Raccoon No need to feel embarassed. I checked it with Chrome Developer Tools, went up the DOM tree until I found a background image on body.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a CSS3 solution on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xde5G/).

Over time this will be preferable to heavy background images: creating them, maintaining them, serving them, downloading them, caching them. With CSS3, these steps are no longer necessary.

Instead, just use CSS3 radial-gradient, and look up what you need with a generator. 
Here is the code:

```
/* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(center, circle farthest-corner, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center, circle farthest-corner, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-radial-gradient(center, circle farthest-corner, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 506, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #00A3EF));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, circle farthest-corner, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at center, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);
```

​
A. For now, it requires vendor prefixes, so that it can render cross browser.

B. Is it hard to write? No. It is trivial! This is also the new way of CSS3. Look up a "CSS3 Generator #what you need#'  In this case it was a radial-gradient. But you can do the same for box-shadow, text-shadow, transform, animation, etc.

[Here is one example of about a hundred diverse CSS3 generators.](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/default.html)

[Here is another jsfiddle involving opacity](http://jsfiddle.net/Xde5G/1/), it is getting closer to the example image.